# Big integration error with integrate.nquad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

Firstly, I integrate a simple function on an ellipse.
Secondly, I integrate the same function to which I add a constant value.
The results are not consistent as you can see on the bottom of my message.

Thanks in advance for you help.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scipy import integrate
from math import *

a = 2.0;
b = 1.0;
Cst = 1.0

def f1(x, y):
    return sqrt(abs(1. -(x/a)**2 -(y/b)**2)) 

def f2(x, y):
    return sqrt(abs(1. -(x/a)**2 -(y/b)**2)) + Cst

def un(x, y):
   return 1.0

def bounds_y():
    return [-b, b]

def bounds_x(y):
    xLimSup = a*sqrt(1-(y/b)**2)
    xLimInf = -xLimSup    
    return [xLimInf, xLimSup]

[S, err] = integrate.nquad(un, [bounds_x, bounds_y])
Stheo = a*b*pi  

[Intf1, err1] = integrate.nquad(f1, [bounds_x, bounds_y]) 
Intf1corr = Intf1 + Cst * S

[Intf2, err2] = integrate.nquad(f2, [bounds_x, bounds_y]) 

print("S     =     %1.4e " % S)
print("Stheo =     %1.4e \n" % Stheo)
print("Intf1 =     %1.4e " % Intf1)
print("Intf1corr = %1.4e " % Intf1corr)
print("Intf2 =     %1.4e " % Intf2) # Ce résultat est complètement faux !!!
```

## **********************************************************

```
S     =     6.2832e+00
Stheo =     6.2832e+00 

Intf1 =     4.1888e+00 
Intf1corr = 1.0472e+01 
Intf2 =     9.7238e-01
```

Comment: Your code works for me (i.e. I get `Intf2 =     1.0472e+01`), using scipy 0.14.0 (with numpy 1.9.1 in python 2.7.8, and with numpy 1.8.1 in python 3.3.5).  Which versions of scipy, numpy and python are you using?  Which operating system?

Comment: I am using Entough Canopy with Python 2.7.6 with Numpy 1.8.1, Scipy 0.14.0 on Win7.

Comment: With similar setup to HDE (Canopy Windows 7: 32-bit, same package versions), I get same results as he does. With same setup on Mac 64-bit, I get same as Warren. I'll check Windows 64-bit later.

Comment: Same on Win-64 as on Win-32. I'll report to Enthought build team.

Comment: @HDE: Does `dblquad` work?  Try `Intdq, errdq = integrate.dblquad(f2, -b, b, lambda y: bounds_x(y)[0], lambda y: bounds_x(y)[1])` and print `Intdq`.

Comment: dblquad does not work : 
'Intf1 =     4.1888e+00 
Intf1corr = 1.0472e+01 
Intf2 =     9.7238e-01 
Intdq =     9.7238e-01 
'

Comment: I obtained the same wrong results after an update of all the packages (numpy and scipy).