# scipy.integrate.quad fails (sometimes) when function to be integrated is also an integral

Tags: python, scipy, quad

I am using `sqipy.integrate.quad` to calculate a double integral. Basically I'm trying to calculate the integral over exp[-mu_wx_par] where mu_wx_par is also a integral.

My code mostly works. However, for some values it fails, i.e. it returns incorrect values.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate


def mu_wx_par(x, year, par):
    """ First function to be integrated """
    m = max(par['alfa'], 0) + par['beta'] * 10 ** (par['gamma'] * x)
    w = np.minimum(par['frem_a'] + par['frem_b'] * x + par['frem_c'] * x**2, 0)
    return m * (1 + w/100)**(year - par['innf_aar'])


def tpx_wx(x, t, par, year):
    """ Second function to be integrated (which contains an integral itself)"""
    result, _ = integrate.quad(lambda s: mu_wx_par(x + s, year + s, par), 0, t)
    return np.exp(-result)


def est_lifetime(x, year, par):
    """ Integral of second function. """
    result, _ = integrate.quad(lambda s: tpx_wx(x, s, par, year), 0, 125 - x)

    return result


# Test variables
par = {'alfa': 0.00019244401470947973,
       'beta': 2.420260552210541e-06,
       'gamma': 0.0525500987420195,
       'frem_a': 0.3244611019518985,
       'frem_b': -0.12382978382606026,
       'frem_c': 0.0011901237463116591,
       'innf_aar': 2018
       }


year = 2018
estimate_42 = est_lifetime(42, year, par)
estimate_43 = est_lifetime(43, year, par)
rough_estimate_42 = sum([tpx_wx(42, t, par, year) for t in range(0, 100)])

print(estimate_42)
print(estimate_43)
print(rough_estimate_42)
3.1184634065887544
46.25925442287578
47.86323490659588
```

The value of `estimate_42` is not correct. It should be about the same value as `rough_estimate_42`. Note however that `estimate_43` looks fine. What is going on here?

I am using scipy v1.1.0 and numpy v1.15.1 and Windows.

It has been suggested that the function is close to zero almost everywhere, as in this post [scipy integrate.quad return an incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044251/scipy-integrate-quad-return-an-incorrect-value). That is not the case as a simple plot of `tpx_wx` for `x=42` from `a=0` to `b=125-42` clearly shows

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(125-42), [tpx_wx(42, t, par, year) for t in range(0, 125-42)])
plt.show()
```

[image: Function to be integrated <code>tpx_wx</code> over integration range]

Comment: WIth SciPy 1.1.0, I get 47.36317494751913 for `estimate_42`,

Comment: Hmm. Im currently not at the office so I can't check my version og scipy. But I found that when I tried to do the integral for multiple x's (say for x between 20 and 80) some would fail whilst others would be ok.

Comment: ... and it seemed pretty random which would fail.

Comment: It is not the same issue. If that was the case, you would not have gotten the correct answer. There is nothing weird about the function at all. The fact that you get a different answer from me is suspiscious in itself. Running my code on a different computer also gave the incorrect answer. :| I use Windows btw. dont know if it matters.

Comment: I also got 3.118... when on Windows. Strange. Anyway, adding `points=[(125-x)/2]`    (in effect, bisecting the range of integration) fixed the issue.

Comment: Bisecting does not fix it. It merely makes quad avoid, in a totally random and unpredictable way, whathever numerical  quirk or bug that caused the error. But anyway I appreciate your efforts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6882) with the way that some Fortran code behind `quad` is compiled for Windows: calling it recursively can lead to failure in some cases. See also [Big integration error with integrate.nquad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270044/big-integration-error-with-integrate-nquad).

Barring recompiling SciPy with better flags, it seems that one should avoid nested integration with `quad` while on Windows. One workaround is to use [`romberg`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.romberg.html) method for one of the integration steps. Replacing `quad` in `est_lifetime` with

```
integrate.romberg(lambda s: tpx_wx(x, s, par, year), 0, 125 - x, divmax=20)
```

results in `47.3631754795` for `estimate_42`, consistent with what `quad` returns on Linux.

---

One way to visualize the process of integration is to declare a global list `eval_points` and insert `eval_points.append(t)` into `tpx_wx`. With the same version of SciPy (0.19.1 in this test), the results of `plt.plot(eval_points, '.')` look different.

On Linux:

[image: linux]

On Windows:

[image: Windows]

Iterated bisection of the neighborhood of a tricky point around 60 is terminated prematurely on Windows, and it seems that the result thrown up is some partial integral over a subinterval.

Comment: Wow! You really went the extra mile here. Thank you. Using a different routine on one of the integrals is probably the way to go. Once again thanks!