# scipy dblquad providing the wrong result in simple double integral

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am trying to calculate a straightforward doble definite integral in Python: function Max(0, (4-12x) + (6-12y)) in the square [0,1] x [0,1].

We can do it with Mathematica and get the exact result:

```
Integrate[Max[0, 4-12*u1 + 6-12*u2], {u1, 0, 1}, {u2, 0,1}] = 125/108.
```

With a simple Monte Carlo simulation I can confirm this result. However, using `scipy.integrate.dblquad` I am getting a value of 0.0005772072907971, with error 0.0000000000031299

```
from scipy.integrate import dblquad

def integ(u1, u2):
    return max(0, (4 - 12*u1) + (6 - 12*u2))
sol_int, err = dblquad(integ, 0, 1, lambda _:0, lambda _:1, epsabs=1E-12, epsrel=1E-12)
print("dblquad: %0.16f. Error: %0.16f" % (sol_int, err) )
```

Agreed that the function is not derivable, but it is continuous, I see no reason for this particular integral to be problematic.

I thought maybe `dblquad` has an 'options' argument where I can try different numerical methods, but I found nothing like that.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I run this using scipy 1.1.0 and numpy 1.15.4, the output is `dblquad: 1.1574073869306833. Error: 0.0000000000031299`

Comment: @Warren thank you, very interesting, that would be correct. I see I am using numpy 1.14.3, scipy 1.1.0. Python 3.6.5

Comment: Are you sure the code that you show in the question is exactly the same as the code that gave you `0.0005772072907971`?

Comment: Yes, I just recopied from this screen to a new file, and executed it. Same 0.000577 result.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  How did you install scipy?  You might be hitting this bug: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6882; see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270044/big-integration-error-with-integrate-nquad

Comment: Yes, I am. Installed everything through Anaconda, when I have time I think I should reinstall to the newest versions, see if the bug remains. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try different numerical methods

That's what I would suggest, given the trouble that iterated `quad` has on Windows. After changing it to an explicit two-step process, you can replace one of `quad` with another method, `romberg` seems the best alternative to me.

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, romberg

def integ(u1, u2):
    return max(0, (4 - 12*u1) + (6 - 12*u2))

sol_int = romberg(lambda u1: quad(lambda u2: integ(u1, u2), 0, 1)[0], 0, 1)    
print("romberg-quad: %0.16f " % sol_int)
```

This prints 1.1574073959987758 on my computer, and hopefully you will get the same.

Comment: This does solve it, thanks! I did not know about the `romberg` function.